# Sequential search 1000 keys in a file of 10000 randoms numbers

Tags: java, arrays

I wrote some code that will run a sequential search for 1000 keys in a file of 10000 random numbers and prints out the keys that arr found .

Here is the code below. When I run it but I am not getting anything. Where is my mistake ?

```
public class SeqSample2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] a;
        double[] b;
        a = new double[10000];
        b = new double[1000];
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            a[i] = (int) ((Math.random() * 10000));
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
            b[j] = (int) ((Math.random() * 1000));
        }

        int lim = a.length - b.length;
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        boolean found = false;
        for (i = 0; i < lim; i++) {

            if (b[0] == a[i]) {
                found = true;

                for (j = 0; j < b.length; j++) {
                    if (b[j] != a[i + j]) {
                        found = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (found) {
                    System.out.println(b[i]);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Not found");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "I run it but I am not getting anything"...you need to be a bit more specific. Do you get any errors? Have you stepped through the code in a debugger?

Comment: i don't get any errors . when i run it i don't get any output.

Comment: How about running the code in a debugger and tell us what you found and what you think might be wrong? Presenting the community with a wall of code and asking it to work out what is wrong, with no visible effort to solve the problem yourself, isn't really what we're here to do. The trick here is to demonstrate that you've done everything to try and find out what is broken - e.g. tell us what you found when you run this in a debugger or logging statements. That's how you'll get folks engaged with your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you surprised?

- `b[0]` is a random number between 0 and 1,000.
- `a[i]` is a random number between 0 and 10,000 for `i < 1,000` and 0 for `i >= 1,000`.

If you run your program a few times, you will eventually get an output, but most of the time, `if (b[0] == a[i])` will be false and the program will exit without printing anything.

Comment: thanks but i don't understand what u mean

Comment: You don't get any output because the condition in your if is false most of the time. If you run your program a few times it might be true (these are random numbers so difficult to predict!).